# Перенести unstage файлы на другую ветку?

Tags: git

Можно ли как нибудь перенести unstage файлы c одной ветки на другую? Например в develop ветке изменил файлы. А нужно было это сделать в ветке newFeatures. Делать коммит в develop нельзя.
Или только вручную придется каждый файл скопировать?

Comment: `$ man git-stash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть команда `stash`:

```
git stash
git checkout newFeatures
git stash apply или git stash pop (если изменения больше не нужны)
```

Comment: Спасибо!
А как отменить примененный 
git stash apply или git stash pop
?